# Wordpress - Can I put functions in a custom template (php file)?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

In wordpress functions.php file you can write all the functions you want. However it often happens that functions.php gets very long due to many functions you can write.

Now what I know is that I can split functions.php file by creating others and including them with `include_once get_theme_file_path`, but I don't like this solution because I don't want any other functions file.

So my question is: is there a way to write functions directly in wordrpress template.php instead of writing them in functions.php?

This would allow me to keep my project tidy. Sorry, I'm new. I don't know if this can actually be done.

Comment: Splitting your code in functions.php up into multiple files is a very common practice and something that I personally always do. A common pattern is to put everything into a subfolder such as `includes` or `inc` with one file for each general concept. So if you have functions dedicated to GravityForms, make a file called `includes/gravityforms.php` and if you have ACF, Relevanssi, CF7, etc., do the same. Yes, you can put functions into template files themselves but certain templates are included multiple times so you should wrap them in `function_exists` checks.

Comment: What if you need to change your theme? Will you have to migrate all those functions, templates, etc? Yes, you will need to do that. The correct place to add functionality to your site is within a plugin, not the theme functions.php file...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am working with a child theme and am trying to change some basic templates like single.php, header.php, search.php etc. I prefer to write functions directly in these templates rather than having subfolders and include files. For example, I don't want to create a functions file for single.php just to write a few lines. I'm looking at `function_exists` but don't understand how to use it.

Comment: @brasofilo, I don't necessarily disagree with you, but I also don't think it is always the case either. Some functions are theme-specific, and I would generally recommend those live in the theme itself, there isn't a need for a plugin. Other things, however, are more generic and might be better in a plugin. For the vast majority of my company's clients, we keep almost everything in the theme itself because our clients don't change themes. If a new theme needs to be created, it will be custom and we'd just bring over the functionality that we want. But that's just our model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **locate_template** method to find and **to load code in functions.php** or any other place in your wordpress template. Just remember to **pass true as second argument** for the locate_template function to actually load it. Here is the documentation for [locate_template method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/).

And here is a code example:

```html
<?php

locate_template('/functions/init.php', true);
locate_template('/functions/widgets_init.php', true);
locate_template('/functions/after_theme_setup.php', true);
locate_template('/functions/wp_enqueue_scripts.php', true);

add_action('init', 'custom_init');
add_action('widgets_init', 'custom_widgets_init');
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_after_setup_theme');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_enqueue_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_enqueue_scripts');

?>
```